# PC How to record phone call - other side speech is NOT recorded?

Tags: audio, voip, recording, audio-recording, audacity

On VOIP phone call, using Zoiper software on computer (Windows 10), I am trying to record the entire phone call conversation but the problem is that Audacity, regardless if incoming ( * ) or outgoing ( ** ) phone call, records only my speech where I am speaking into the microphone. Incoming voice, from the person on the other side, is not being recorded and/or recording volume is zero.

If I listen EXTREMELY carefully then I hear very very very quiet voice from the other side into the recorded (exported) file as mp3 so I believe the problem is that recording of the other side of phone call is basically zero or almost zero volume. I don't know how to increase the volume? But volume of my own speech on recorded phone calls is good.

( * ) i receive the phone call when someone else calls me

( ** ) i am the one who executes the phone call and call someone else

Would anyone please help? I must have entire phone call recorded and not only my own speech.

Comment: You may want to try different sound devices in Audacity and see if one of those makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to loop audio output back to some (either physical or virtual) audio input, but this would be very impractical. You would have to run two audacity instances or find a way to mix two inputs.
Switch to softphone that supports call recording.